# R: Plot two different datasets on the same world map

Tags: r

I am new to R. Currently I am trying to plot two different datasets on world map. I am using package rworldmap.
My data:

```
> dput(array_with_data1)
structure(list(Country = structure(c(35L, 7L, 57L, 42L, 55L, 
3L, 12L, 2L, 58L, 63L, 19L, 15L, 10L, 45L, 30L, 70L, 14L, 6L, 
38L, 43L, 9L, 54L, 68L, 31L, 22L, 36L, 25L, 61L, 16L, 23L, 69L, 
51L, 20L, 62L, 17L, 37L, 39L, 56L, 59L, 26L, 27L, 50L, 71L, 48L, 
60L, 24L, 44L, 66L, 46L, 67L, 52L, 32L, 21L, 49L, 72L, 13L, 5L, 
11L, 34L, 1L, 40L, 8L, 65L, 53L, 64L, 28L, 33L, 18L, 4L, 41L, 
47L, 29L), .Label = c("Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Bangladesh", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Canada", 
"Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
"Denmark", "Egypt", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Georgia", 
"Germany", "Greece", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "India", "Indonesia", 
"Iran", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", 
"Kosovo", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lithuania", "Malaysia", "Mexico", 
"Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nigeria", "Norway", 
"Pakistan", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", 
"Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovakia", 
"Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "St. Helena", 
"Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Turkey", "Ukraine", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Venezuela", 
"Vietnam"), class = "factor"), `Variable1` = c(100, NA, 59, 
NA, 52, 37, 37, NA, 35, 34, 32, 31, 30, 30, 28, NA, 27, 26, 25, 
25, 25, 24, 24, 23, NA, 23, 23, 23, 22, 22, NA, 20, 20, 20, 19, 
NA, 19, 18, 16, 14, NA, 13, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, NA, 10, 10, 
10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA, 
3, 3)), .Names = c("Country", "Variable1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = "data.frame")


> dput(array_with_data2)
structure(list(Country = structure(c(35L, 7L, 57L, 42L, 55L, 
3L, 12L, 2L, 58L, 63L, 19L, 15L, 10L, 45L, 30L, 70L, 14L, 6L, 
38L, 43L, 9L, 54L, 68L, 31L, 22L, 36L, 25L, 61L, 16L, 23L, 69L, 
51L, 20L, 62L, 17L, 37L, 39L, 56L, 59L, 26L, 27L, 50L, 71L, 48L, 
60L, 24L, 44L, 66L, 46L, 67L, 52L, 32L, 21L, 49L, 72L, 13L, 5L, 
11L, 34L, 1L, 40L, 8L, 65L, 53L, 64L, 28L, 33L, 18L, 4L, 41L, 
47L, 29L), .Label = c("Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Bangladesh", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Canada", 
"Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
"Denmark", "Egypt", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Georgia", 
"Germany", "Greece", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "India", "Indonesia", 
"Iran", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", 
"Kosovo", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lithuania", "Malaysia", "Mexico", 
"Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nigeria", "Norway", 
"Pakistan", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", 
"Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovakia", 
"Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "St. Helena", 
"Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Turkey", "Ukraine", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Venezuela", 
"Vietnam"), class = "factor"), `Variable2` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
54, NA, NA, NA, 36, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
19, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Country", "Variable2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = "data.frame")
```

Type of array_with_data1 is a list. The first column (Country) contains names of countries. The second column (Variable1) contains numerical variable that I represented on the map, same colour, different brightnes, using the following piece of code:

```
library(rworldmap)

plot_dataset <- function(array_with_data1){
    sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(array_with_data1,
                          joinCode = "NAME",
                          nameJoinColumn = "Country",
                          mapResolution = "coarse"
    )
    mapParams <- mapCountryData( sPDF,
                           nameColumnToPlot= "Variable1",
                           addLegend=FALSE,
                           oceanCol="lightblue",
                           missingCountryCol=NA
    )
}

map <- plot_dataset(array_with_data1)
```

Now I would like to add another dataset (array_with_data2) on the same map with different colour to overlay with the first dataset.

Comment: Images are a bad way to share data - please share R code to create those objects. `dput(object)` will create such code for you. Otherwise your question looks nicely reproducible for a first question!

Comment: If you leave that data as pictures it means you expect any potential answerer to redo your data entry. Learn to use `dput(your_data-frame)`. I'd say most of us will simply ignore (boycott) such questions and eventually close them. I generally wait about 2 hours before I cast a close vote but others will vote to close even quicker.

Comment: Done. I have replaced images with dput(my_data-frame). Thank you for advice.